Best solution was not repeated - no reliable result for metaMDS?
I have abundance data of spiders that I captured in different forest stands and I want to perform an NMDS. It generally works, although the stress value is relatively high. However, I get the message that the best solution could not be repeated.

```Spiders_NMDS <- metaMDS(nmds_data[,7:54], k = 2, distance = "horn", trymax= 100, maxit=1000 )

Here are the last lines of the output:
Run 100 stress 0.2085273
... Procrustes: rmse 0.008630914 max resid 0.05303693
*** Best solution was not repeated -- monoMDS stopping criteria:
100: stress ratio > sratmax

and the output from print(Spiders_NMDS)
metaMDS(comm = nmds_data[, 7:54], distance = "horn", k = 2, trymax = 100, maxit = 1000)

global Multidimensional Scaling using monoMDS

Data: wisconsin(nmds_data[, 7:54])
Distance: horn

Dimensions: 2
Stress: 0.208454
Stress type 1, weak ties
Best solution was not repeated after 100 tries
The best solution was from try 75 (random start)
Scaling: centring, PC rotation, halfchange scaling
Species: expanded scores based on ‘wisconsin(nmds_data[, 7:54])


I read in another forum that it is statistically not really valid to rely on this data and use it in further analyses. Is that correct? After all, the official R site says that you can still use the data, but the concerns from the mentioned forum are certainly not unfounded... see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741 ... -nmds-in-r
Suggestions given by R for this problem unfortunately do not help me. See: https://rdrr.io/cran/vegan/man/metaMDS.html (section 'Results could not be repeated')
For example, I have already increased maxit and trymax, but the message is still output. I have also run another iteration with previous.best
metaMDS(nmds_data[,7:54], k = 2, distance = "horn",trymax= 100, maxit= 100, previous.best = Spiders_NMDS)
However, this does not change the output either.
Increasing the dimensions also does not bring any change and is, for example, not useful in terms of visualization, right?
Does anyone have experience with this problem? Are there ways to achieve more reliable results?
I would like to continue with the envfit function....
My dataset generally contains many zeros and there are probably many traps that have a very large distance from each other (that do not share any species) ...maybe that is important?
Thank you for your feedback :)
PS: a further problem I encountered:
When I try to check for differences in communitystructure by using stand as a grouping variable I receive higly significant results from a adonis2 analysis. But there is no obvious difference between those groups according to the visulization. Did I discover an unknown phenomenon? :D

##############UPDATE
Thank's so far for the help !
I'm still dealing with optimising my NMDS and I probably found a better solution to plot my data.
First I maybe have to describe the study design a bit more in detail.
I had 8 locations, from which 4 were in a northern region and four in a southern region.
Within each location I had 5 plots. Each plot represented a certain stand-type (pure Douglas-fir, pure Beech, pure Spruce, mixed Douglas-fir/beech and mixed spruce/beech. And in each plot I had 4 pitfall traps.
The way I did the first NMDS:
I used the Data per trap, so for each stand-type category 4 (traps per plot) * 8 (locations) = 30 traps per stand type --> NMDS didn't find a soulution
What I changed:
I switched from analysing on the trap level to analysing at the plot level. So for every plot, I just summed up the abundances per species.
When I do it like this and use 3 axes, I get the output that the NMDS reached a solution, so I think I can return to using envfit
:)
so, now it works, but I'm still insecure about some things:

when I use

nmds <- metaMDS(matrix_env_plot[,5:52], k = 3, distance = "horn" )

R applies automatically a wisconsin double standardization.
I read that it enhances the patterns in the data, but I don't really understand what exact use I have from using it and I don't understand what this means for interpreting the results.
The authors of another paper also analyzed spider-species abundance data in winter, they used Hellinger transformation before applying the NMDS with bray-curtis dissimilarity.
But my supervisor told me to use Morisita-Horn as dissimilarity measure ("horn" in vegdist)
Now I wonder if it makes sense for my data, to use the Hellinger transformation (calculating the relative abundances per sample and square-root-transform them), instead of the wisconsin double standardization and than using Morisita-Horn.
I understood, that the hellinger transformation is useful when you want to lessen the influence of the very abundant species.
so for example: two samples from my community matrix:
1.4: 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
4.2:
0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0
(abundances of 11 and 14 belong to a shared species and 1 and 6)
when I use the "horn" index without any transformation i receive a value of 0.1310861, which means that they are quite similar to each other concerning the species and their relative abundances in the samples, and it's also obvious when looking at the data (because of the species with 11 and 14 individuals).
but when I apply the hellinger transformation before, I get a value of 0.33205, so they are less similar, as they do not share the species with the low abundances.
Does it makes sense to apply this transformation? On the one hand I would say yes, as there are more information included about the species which have lower abundances, but on the other hand, species with such low abundances might just not have been captured in another stand, even though they are also there...so it is too much including those random sampling effects....
I'm a little bit overwhelmed as I really try to understand what I'm doing and the whole topic of data-transformation seems complex to me.
Generally what I would like to evaluate is if there are differences in the spider-communites between the stand-types and the way I think about it in detail:
is there a differences between the occuring species in the different stand-types+ does the relative abundance structure vary between the stand types.
I think the morisita-horn index combines both information.
I also add an extract from my data-matrix. I get the feeling, that my data are not too meaningful beaucause of the low abundances and that I shoud have installed more traps. But now I have to work with the data I have :)
So finally my most urgent questions is:
Is using the hellinger transformation and afterwards the morista -horn index a good combination to use for my NMDS?


I have seen diagnostics like these with pitfall trap data used in a lab exercise for my Ecology students.  It is likely you have many rare species scattered among your traps - a sparse matrix (many zeroes) and metaMDS struggles to find any structure that can be represented in few dimensions.  If there was clear structure in your data, 100 runs from random starting points should find it (or something very close) repeatedly.  The relatively high stress is also consistent with this.  I would not recommend using envfit with results like these.  Envfit works with distances in ordination space and since your ordination is not a repeatable and reliable summary of the data the results from envfit will be meaningless.  Two suggestions:

Use vegan::adonis (PERMANOVA) instead of envfit because it uses the raw distances (in ecological space) not the distances in your unreliable ordination space.  You wont get a "visualization" but can test for differences between your stands or any other grouping or gradient of samples.

Consider the analysis at a higher taxonomic level (genera, families, or perhaps functional groups) as you will have a less sparse matrix and patterns could be clearer.  That will still allow you test for differences in spider communities among your forest stands, but without the noise from many rare species.


I agree, your NMDS ordination is disappointing.  Each stand seems to cover almost all of ordination space.  You could try using ordispider or ordihull to make any small differences among the stands clearer, but in this case I doubt if that will make you any happier.
The problem is that the pattern in you data is not very strong or too complex to be represented in 2 dimensions (high stress). Your results with adonis show that there are differences among your stands but that is clearly not the main pattern in your data (depicted in the first 2 NMDS dimensions).  Also, adonis tells you that the differences are statistically significant but not whether they are big/clear differences.  Consider a simple linear regression with a large sample size.  You might find a highly significant slope but a low r-squared.  The graph looks like a random scatter (low r-sq) but there is a weak pattern in there and you can be confident that the slope is not zero (small p-value).  You seem to have 30 samples for each Stand - I consider that a big sample size.  In your case, there is a further problem - the weak but significant pattern may not be visible in the reduced dimensionality of your plot (it might be clearer in 3 dimensions but maybe only appears in the 4th or 5th axes).
Perhaps there is a pattern in your first two NMDS axes, just not related to the two grouping variables you have considered.  Maybe something else like proximity of the trap to another habitat, or particular features of the trap location (e.g. wet/dry, depth of leaf litter) is giving you different spider assemblages that are picked up by NMDS.  Have a think about other factors/gradients that might be more important than Stand or Region.
However, if comparison of Stands and identifying which species respond most to this factor are the only things you are interested in then perhaps consider a more direct approach like discriminant analysis, indicator species analysis or SIMPER.

Thanks so mich for your suggestions ! I'm very glad to have received your reply!
Yes, for me it's excactly the same...pitfall-trap data which I recorded in winter.
I applied PERMANOVA to check for differences between my forest-stand-types. First I could make sure, that the dispersions are not significantly different (with betadisper). Than I applyed PERMANOVA and R retourned a higly significant Pr(>F). But I really wonder, because on the NMDS visulization there seems no difference. I can't explain why i receive this result from the PERMANOVA. When I use anosim it's the same.

I also added a picture from the NMDS in my question :)

Thank's again for your explanations and suggestions. This was really helpful in order to understand! I also wrote a little update regarding my progess and some new difficulties which I encountered .....
